# Update one list when another is updated

Tags: designer-workflow

I have two lists.  List 1 is Project Dashboard (has information about different projects such as project name, status, phase percent complete, project manager, etc) and list 2 is Project Review (has information around the project and the quality review info such as project name, status, quality review date, quality review outcome, etc).  I have created a workflow using the Create Item when an item in List 1 is added it creates a new item in List 2 using list 1's information (project name, status, and List 1 Id (this is the ID SparePoint assigns for each item)).  I would like to have a workflow update List 2 if any of the information in List 1 changes for example if the status changes from active to on hold.  I tried creating a workflow using Update item but it is not working.  Is it possible to update List 2 when List 1 is updated using workflows?

Comment: I would not duplicate the same data in two lists. Use a lookup column in List2 to look up a project in List1 and carry all pertinent fields over with the lookup. Then changes to List1 fields will automatically be reflected in List2.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can. When you create item in list 2 keep a lookup column pointing to ID for list 1. 
So when any changes are made to list 1 search for the item in List 2 with column values as List1_ID. 
This approach will work assuming you have only 1 item in list 2 corresponding to list1.

Answer (score 1):

I would add an event receiver to List 1 with an item updated event. You can use the event to perform actions on the second list based on the altered information in List 1.